# Objective-C: UITabBarController with splitted views

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm quite new to Objective-C and I'm trying to write my first app for iOS. The idea is quite simple but I have failed already in the beginning architecture construction.

I would like to create different views displayed over several tabs, which should be created dynamically when the view is loaded. Additionally, the app must have the ability to add tabs dynamically at runtime. Tab views should not run over the entire screen but should fill 2/3 of the top view. The remaining 1/3 at the bottom is again divided into two subviews, which are not intended to be changed with tab switches.

What I've done is to create a UIWindow, UITabBarController, and two UIViewControllers (for two tabs) and one (or two as in the figure) which is supposed to be at the bottom.

So far I've managed to switch between different tab views, but as soon as I try to resize UIViewControllers for both tabs with CGMakeRect to any size it always stays the same and covers the entire screen.

The subview created at the bottom contains a button which is somehow not clickable. Maybe because it's covered from the tab views.

Can anyone give me a little help how I can build up those views?

Thanks a lot!

Here is be my code:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];


UIViewController *test = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
test.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
test.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200);

UIButton *button3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button3 setTitle:@"View 3" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button3.frame = CGRectMake(30.0, 30.0, 120.0, 50.0);
[test.view addSubview:button3];


UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

UIViewController *viewController1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UITabBarItem *tab1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemBookmarks tag:1];
[viewController1 setTabBarItem:tab1];

UIViewController *viewController2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UITabBarItem *tab2 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemContacts tag:2];
[viewController2 setTabBarItem:tab2];


UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setTitle:@"View from Tab 1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 120.0, 50.0);
[viewController1.view addSubview:button];

UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button2 setTitle:@"View from Tab 2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button2.frame = CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 120.0, 50.0);
[viewController2.view addSubview:button2];


tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil];

self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
[self.window addSubview:test.view];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: You rock for creating your GUI programmatically! +1. However, in the future, please refrain from writing 'Xcode development' or similar, because, for your information, Xcode is not really essential or particularly relevant for this case (you could use nano and make for writing apps.).

Comment: Sadly you may find that you can't do what you want to do - the `UITabBarController` must (according to the docs) be the rootViewController (which you've done) but it specifically doesn't play nice with others encroaching on its turf. You might try embedding the tab bar controller in a `ContentView` within a parent `UIViewController` but if this is going into the app store I don't know Apple's checking/policy on using the `UITabBarController` this way.

Comment: It is possible, see my answer below. It may not be the prettiest way, but it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a way to achieve that thanks to custom container view controllers:

Replace the `UITabBarController` with a custom subclass of `UIViewController` as rootViewController of the window. Then in it's `viewDidLoad` method (or somewhere else depending on your needs) you add almost your exact code from above with some minor modifications. Here's the complete code for the `viewDidLoad` method (I've added comments above the modified lines):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    //Mod1: Set an autoresizingMask 
    //so that the view always fills the tabBarController's view
    //if needed you can also set it's frame here
    viewController1.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    UITabBarItem *tab1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemBookmarks tag:1];
    [viewController1 setTabBarItem:tab1];

    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    //Mod2: Same here
    viewController2.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    UITabBarItem *tab2 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemContacts tag:2];
    [viewController2 setTabBarItem:tab2];


    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button setTitle:@"View from Tab 1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 120.0, 50.0);
    [viewController1.view addSubview:button];

    UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button2 setTitle:@"View from Tab 2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button2.frame = CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 120.0, 50.0);
    [viewController2.view addSubview:button2];

    tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil];


    //Mod3: Set the frame and autoresizingMask of the tabBarController 
    //to fill the rootVC's view
    tabBarController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    tabBarController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;


    //Mod4: This is the important part:
    //add the tabBarController as childVC of the rootVC
    [self addChildViewController:tabBarController];
    [self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [tabBarController didMoveToParentViewController:self];



    //Mod5: calculate the frame for the 'static' vc on the bottom
    float heightForStaticVC = 200.0f;

    float yPosForStaticVC = tabBarController.view.frame.size.height - tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height - heightForStaticVC;


    UIViewController *test = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    //Mod6: again setting the autoresizingMask
    test.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    test.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    test.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, yPosForStaticVC, 320, heightForStaticVC);

    UIButton *button3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button3 setTitle:@"View 3" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button3.frame = CGRectMake(30.0, 30.0, 120.0, 50.0);
    [test.view addSubview:button3];

    //Mod7: and again adding it as childVC of the rootVC
    [self addChildViewController:test];
    [self.view addSubview:test.view];
    [test didMoveToParentViewController:self];

}
```

Of course you can modify sizing, positioning and autoresizing behavior as you want.

The result looks like this:

[image: Tab1 Portrait] [image: Tab2 Portrait]

[image: Tab1 Landscape]

[image: Tab2 Landscape]